# How to pass function to Ractive Components?

Tags: ractivejs

I want to pass a function to the Ractive template and want to trigger it when there is some action in the component. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There's several ways to do this.

You can provide a method

```js
const Component = Ractive.extend({
  template: `
    <button type="button" on-click="@this.myMethod()">Click Me</button>
  `,
  myMethod: function() {
    console.log('Hello World!');
  }
});

new Component({
  el: 'body'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ractive/ractive.min.js"></script>
```

Or attach an event listener in one of the lifecycle events

```js
const Component = Ractive.extend({
  template: `
    <button type="button" on-click="someevent">Click Me</button>
  `,
  oninit: function() {
    this.on('someevent', function() {
      console.log('Hello World!');
    });
  }
});

new Component({
  el: 'body'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ractive/ractive.min.js"></script>
```

Ractive also supports data functions (literally functions inside your data)

```js
const Component = Ractive.extend({
  template: `
    <button type="button" on-click="this.myDataFunction()">Click Me</button>
  `,
  data: {
    myDataFunction: function(){
      console.log('Hello World!');
    }
  }
});

new Component({
  el: 'body'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ractive/ractive.min.js"></script>
```

If you have a function on the parent component that you want called by a child component event, simply fire an event on the child component. You can do this by assigning an event name or manually using `ractive.fire` (useful if you want to pass arguments). Then you assign on the parent template your event handler or method.

```js
const Child = Ractive.extend({
  template: `
    <button type="button" on-click="customclick" on-mouseover="@this.fire('custommouseover', 'Hello', 'World')">Click Me</button>
  `
});

const Parent = Ractive.extend({
  components: { Child },
  template: `
    <Child on-customclick="@this.myMethod()" on-custommouseover="mouseovered" />
  `,
  myMethod: function(){
    console.log('clicked');
  },
  oninit: function() {
    this.on('mouseovered', function(foo, bar) {
      console.log('mouseovered', foo, bar);
    });
  }
});

new Parent({
  el: 'body'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ractive/ractive.min.js"></script>
```

You can mix and match the use of event, method calls and data functions however you like. You can have the button call a method that in turn calls `ractive.fire`, have an event handler that calls `ractive.fire`, assign an event name that gets received by the parent, call `ractive.fire` directly from the template, etc. You can even pass in the parent function as data and call it like a data function on the child. Choose whatever works for you.

Comment: I have function in parent component and I want to pass that to child component.